# ASP OnText event based controlling button control

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

What I'm trying to do is has a specific button enables or disables based on the number of characters that have been imputed into a textbox.

The event only fire when I click off the textbox, maybe i'm looking for something else?

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="InputVinInformationTextBox" runat="server"
    Skin="Office2010Blue"
    Width="250px"
    MaxLength="16"
    OnTextChanged="InputVinInformationTextBox_OnText"
    AutoPostBack="true">
</telerik:RadTextBox>

protected void InputVinInformationTextBox_OnText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InputVinInformationTextBox.Text.Length >= 8)
    {
        VinSubmitButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        VinSubmitButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using jQuery you could remove the `OnTextChanged` function and instead bind the functionality to the `keyup` event.  All you need to do is to add the following in your `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=InputVinInformationTextBox.ClientID%>").keyup(function() {
            if (InputVinInformationTextBox.Text.Length >= 8)
            {
               VinSubmitButton.Enabled = true;    
            }
            else
            {
                VinSubmitButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure what your VinSubmitButton is, but I assume, since it was working in your example, that that is an element that you already have stored.

Comment: Jonas using my example above, where do I actually plug that in?

Comment: @Mike all you need to do is to add a reference to the `jQuery library`  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`. The `$("#<%=InputVinInformationTextBox.ClientID%>")` code selects your rad control, and the `.keyup(function() {` binds that control's keyup event to the following function.

Comment: @Mike I updated my answer to include how to reference jQuery. Other that this, no other code would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design:

> All RadInput controls provide the TextChanged server event, which is
>   raised when the AutoPostBack property is set to true, the user types
>   valid entry, and the input loses focus.
>
> The TextChanged event only occurs if the value of the input control
>   actually changes. If the user changes the string in the input control
>   but does not actually change the value...the TextChanged event does
>   not occur.

See this [help topic](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-server-ontextchanged.html) on Telerik's site for more info.

I recommend using the `OnTextChanged` event as you have been, as it will only fire when valid text is entered that changes the previous value of the `RadTextBox`.

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to determine when an appropriate number of characters have been entered, then trigger the request manually.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="InputVinInformationTextBox" runat="server"
    Skin="Office2010Blue"
    Width="250px"
    MaxLength="16"
    OnLoad="InputVinInformationTextBox_OnLoad">
    <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="InputVinInformationTextBox_OnKeyPress" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function InputVinInformationTextBox_OnKeyPress(sender, args) {
        var text = sender.get_value();
        if (text.length >= 8) {
            var ajaxManager = $find('<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page) %>');
            ajaxManager.ajaxRequestWithTarget(sender.get_id(), '');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The code above assumes you are also using a `RadAjaxManager` on the page and that it has been configured to update all/part of the page when triggered by the `RadTextBox`. You'd need to check the RadTextBox value during the `OnLoad` event of the control (or later) so that all ViewState and form values have been initialized for the control.

```
protected void InputVinInformationTextBox_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InputVinInformationTextBox.Text.Length >= 8)
    {
        VinSubmitButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        VinSubmitButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```